# How to properly merge more than 2 Eloquent Collections in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

My issue right now is whenever I create **two** new assignments, the last `Post` in the merged collection disappears.

```
// Here is the code: 
@foreach($user->groups as $group)
    <?php
    $all = $group->posts->merge($group->assignments)->merge($group->quizzes);

    $sorted = $all->sortByDesc('created_at');
    ?>
        @foreach($sorted as $item)
        <?php
        $val = get_class($item);
            switch ($val)
        {
            case 'App\Post':
            ?>
                Post:{{$item->body}}<br>    
            <?php
                break;
            case 'App\Assignment':
                ?>
                Assignment:{{$item->title}}<br>

                <?php
                break;
            case 'App\Quiz':
            ?>
                Quiz:{{$item->body}}<br>

            <?php
                break;
        }
        ?>
    @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

So how can I properly merge various Eloquent Collections together, then sort them by the latest?

Answer (score 0):

When you merge Eloquent collections, models' primary keys are used to identify duplicates. Therefore, assignments will overwrite posts with the same ID and then quizes will overwrite posts and assignments with the same ID.

In order to achieve what you want, you'll need to convert Eloquent collections to regular collections indexed by integers using **values()** method.

Replace:

```
$all = $group->posts->merge($group->assignments)->merge($group->quizzes);
```

with

```
$all = $group->posts->values()->merge($group->assignments->values())->merge($group->quizzes->values());
```

Comment: I have an error and the error is "Call to a member function values() on null"

Comment: Do you have posts, assignments and quizes relations defined in your group model? One of them is missing, it might be a typo in relations name

Comment: Yes, the posts, assignments,and quizzes model are connected to Group model and their relationship is Many to Many.

Comment: Again, one of $group->posts, $group->assignments or $group->quizzes is null, check which of them and make sure the relation is there. One of them is missing, otherwise you'd get a Collection object, not null. Try dd($group->posts, $group->assignments, $group->quizzes) and check which one

Comment: How can I output them even if they are empty?. Because once the professor created any one of those it will be posted automatically in the newsfeed.